# i wanted to save my data on listview after clicking the back button and also view it after pressing view button.But i am not getting it

Tags: android, listview

I have a Recyclerview in my main activity and a button on a every fragment of recyclerview. When i click on that button the data just get added to listview present on another activity. And I have a button present on my action bar, when i click that button wants to see only the list view. Thanks in Advance.
My MainAcitivity code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

//    ArrayList<Integer> images;
//    ArrayList<String> imageNames, contents;
    public static int[] images = {R.drawable.bengalithali,R.drawable.chikanthali,R.drawable.eggthali, R.drawable.gujratithali,
            R.drawable.maharstrianthali, R.drawable.keralathali, R.drawable.rajsthanithali, R.drawable.tamilthali};
    public static String[] imageNames = {"Bengali Thali","Chikan Thali", "Egg Thali", "Gujrathi Thali", "Maharashtrian Thali", "Kerala Thali",
                            "Rajsthani Thali", "Tamil Thali"};
    public static String[] contents = {"As seen in Pic","As seen in Pic","As seen in Pic","As seen in Pic","As seen in Pic","As seen in Pic",
            "As seen in Pic","As seen in Pic"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

//        images = new ArrayList<>();
//        images.add(R.drawable.bengalithali);
//        images.add(R.drawable.chikanthali);
//        images.add(R.drawable.eggthali);
//        images.add(R.drawable.gujratithali);
//        images.add(R.drawable.maharstrianthali);
//        images.add(R.drawable.keralathali);
//        images.add(R.drawable.rajsthanithali);
//        images.add(R.drawable.tamilthali);
//
//        imageNames = new ArrayList<>();
//        imageNames.add("Bengali Thali");
//        imageNames.add("Chikan Thali");
//        imageNames.add("Egg Thali");
//        imageNames.add("Gujrathi Thali");
//        imageNames.add("Maharashtrian Thali");
//        imageNames.add("Kerala Thali");
//        imageNames.add("Rajsthani Thali");
//        imageNames.add("Tamil Thali");
//
//        contents = new ArrayList<>();
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");
//        contents.add("As seen in Pic");


        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this,images, imageNames, contents);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_button,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyCartList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

My Recyclerview adapter code is as follows:
public class RecyclerAdapter extends

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {


     String[]  imageNames, contents;
     int[] images;
     Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,int[] images,String[] imageNames,String[] contents) {
        this.images = images;
        this.imageNames = imageNames;
        this.contents = contents;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
      public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder rvh = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        return rvh;
    }

    @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.productImage.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        holder.productImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        holder.productName.setText(imageNames[position]);
        holder.productContent.setText(contents[position]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView productImage;
        TextView productName, productContent, quantity;
        CircleButton plusButton, minusButton;
        FButton addToCartButton;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            productImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            productContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_content);
            plusButton = (CircleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus_button);
            minusButton = (CircleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus_button);
            quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_quantity);
            addToCartButton = (FButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);


            plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int Quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(Quantity+1));
                    if (Quantity == 10 && plusButton.isClickable()){
                        quantity.setText("10");
                    }
                }
            });

            minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int Quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
                    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(Quantity-1));
                    if (Quantity == 0 && minusButton.isClickable()){
                        quantity.setText("0");
                    }
                }
            });

            addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyCartList.class);
//                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//                    bundle.putString("KEYONE",imageNames[getAdapterPosition()]);
//                    bundle.putString("KEYTWO", contents[getAdapterPosition()]);
//                    intent.putExtras(bundle);

                   intent.putExtra("KEYONE", imageNames[getAdapterPosition()]);
                  intent.putExtra("KEYTWO", contents[getAdapterPosition()]);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                   Toast.makeText(context, ""+imageNames[getAdapterPosition()]+ "\n"+ contents[getAdapterPosition()], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

My CartList activity code is as follows:

```
public class MyCartList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myList = null;
    MyListViewAdapter myListViewAdapter;
    public static ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> d = new ArrayList<>();

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_cart_list);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String a = i.getStringExtra("KEYONE");
        String b = i.getStringExtra("KEYTWO");

        c.add(a);
        d.add(b);

        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
        myListViewAdapter = new MyListViewAdapter(MyCartList.this,c,d);
        myList.setAdapter(myListViewAdapter);

    }
}
```

My listview adapter code is as follows:

```
public class MyListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context mContext;
   public static ArrayList<String> thaliNames, thaliContent;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> thaliNames, ArrayList<String> thaliContent) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.thaliNames = thaliNames;
        this.thaliContent = thaliContent;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return thaliNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);


        TextView listItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_product_name);
        listItem.setText(thaliNames + "\n" + thaliContent);
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gaurya.carttask.MainActivity"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_tems.xml is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:riv_border_color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
        app:riv_oval="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
                android:id="@+id/plus_button"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:cb_color="#64daed"
                android:src="@drawable/plus"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/show_quantity"
                android:layout_width="40sp"
                android:layout_height="40sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
                android:id="@+id/minus_button"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                app:cb_color="#64daed"
                android:src="@drawable/negative"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add to cart"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_my_cart_list.xml is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_my_cart_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gaurya.carttask.MyCartList">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my_list.xml is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: posting your code simply don't give your problem.Please make a clear statement on what you did and how you needed it to be along with where you've gone wrong also.

Comment: In my code there is a recyclerview on one its tab there is a add to cart button. When i click on that button i wanted only the name and content of that tab will go to the list view of another activity. but i don't want to see it on that button click. I want to see that list on another button click which is on my action bar.  Just like on online shopping app we add that item to cart but can not see it. but we ca see it on clicking on cart. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way is, You can create one public class which can hold List of Elements and you can access it whenever you want.

**Example by Using String Object**

```
public static class MyListHolder{

static List<String> lstOfObj;

public Static MyListHolder(){
   lstOfObj = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public static void addNewObject(String object){
    lstOfObj.add(object);
}

public static List<String> getMyObjList(){
    return lstOfObj;
}
}
```

Now You can use this class & methods to manage your List of Object.